# Get Evernote notebook name from webhook

Tags: php, webhooks, evernote

Have functioning webhook from Evernote using Cloud SDK PHP.  Webhooks provide "notebookGuid" and I'm looking for simple way to get and use notebook name using getnotebook function.  Below is NOT working.

```
$guid = $_GET['notebookGuid']; //guid from webhook
$notebook_object = $noteStore->getNotebook($access_token, $guid); //tried with and without the $access_token

if ($notebook_object->name = 'myname') { //is name case-insensitive?
$dosomething=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your code failing? It looks like you may just be doing your equality check wrong, `$notebook_object->name = 'myname'` is an assignment. You probably want something like [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php).